# Serving django app with apache2+mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

I have configured a linode server with apache2 and mod_wsgi..

1. the server is running
2. wsgi is running
3. postgre is running and syncdb was successful

what I am having trouble finishing is actually serving the app..

my file structure:

```
.
├── logfile
└── srv
    ├── logfile
    └── www
        └── quickerhub.com
            ├── admin
            │   ├── css
            │   │   ├── base.css
            │   │   ├── changelists.css
            │   │   ├── dashboard.css
            │   │   ├── forms.css
            │   │   ├── ie.css
            │   │   ├── login.css
            │   │   ├── rtl.css
            │   │   └── widgets.css
            │   ├── img
            │   │   ├── changelist-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── changelist-bg_rtl.gif
            │   │   ├── chooser-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── chooser_stacked-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── default-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── default-bg-reverse.gif
            │   │   ├── deleted-overlay.gif
            │   │   ├── gis
            │   │   │   ├── move_vertex_off.png
            │   │   │   └── move_vertex_on.png
            │   │   ├── icon_addlink.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_alert.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_calendar.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_changelink.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_clock.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_deletelink.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_error.gif
            │   │   ├── icon-no.gif
            │   │   ├── icon_searchbox.png
            │   │   ├── icon_success.gif
            │   │   ├── icon-unknown.gif
            │   │   ├── icon-yes.gif
            │   │   ├── inline-delete-8bit.png
            │   │   ├── inline-delete.png
            │   │   ├── inline-restore-8bit.png
            │   │   ├── inline-restore.png
            │   │   ├── inline-splitter-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── nav-bg.gif
            │   │   ├── nav-bg-grabber.gif
            │   │   ├── nav-bg-reverse.gif
            │   │   ├── nav-bg-selected.gif
            │   │   ├── selector-icons.gif
            │   │   ├── selector-search.gif
            │   │   ├── sorting-icons.gif
            │   │   ├── tool-left.gif
            │   │   ├── tool-left_over.gif
            │   │   ├── tool-right.gif
            │   │   ├── tool-right_over.gif
            │   │   ├── tooltag-add.gif
            │   │   ├── tooltag-add_over.gif
            │   │   ├── tooltag-arrowright.gif
            │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright_over.gif
            │   └── js
            │       ├── actions.js
            │       ├── actions.min.js
            │       ├── admin
            │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
            │       │   ├── ordering.js
            │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
            │       ├── calendar.js
            │       ├── collapse.js
            │       ├── collapse.min.js
            │       ├── core.js
            │       ├── getElementsBySelector.js
            │       ├── inlines.js
            │       ├── inlines.min.js
            │       ├── jquery.init.js
            │       ├── jquery.js
            │       ├── jquery.min.js
            │       ├── LICENSE-JQUERY.txt
            │       ├── prepopulate.js
            │       ├── prepopulate.min.js
            │       ├── SelectBox.js
            │       ├── SelectFilter2.js
            │       ├── timeparse.js
            │       └── urlify.js
            ├── interest
            │   ├── django.wsgi
            │   ├── __init__.py
            │   ├── __init__.pyc
            │   ├── settings.py
            │   ├── settings.pyc
            │   ├── urls.py
            │   └── wsgi.py
            ├── js
            │   └── jquery-1.10.1.min.js
            ├── logfile
            ├── manage.py
            ├── README
            ├── reoccurring
            │   ├── admin.py
            │   ├── forms.py
            │   ├── __init__.py
            │   ├── __init__.pyc
            │   ├── models.py
            │   ├── models.pyc
            │   ├── usagelib.py
            │   └── views.py
            ├── schedule
            │   ├── admin.py
            │   ├── __init__.py
            │   ├── __init__.pyc
            │   ├── models.py
            │   ├── models.pyc
            │   ├── tests.py
            │   ├── usagelib.py
            │   └── views.py
            ├── src
            │   ├── facebooksdk
            │   │   ├── examples
            │   │   │   ├── appengine
            │   │   │   │   ├── app.yaml
            │   │   │   │   ├── example.html
            │   │   │   │   └── example.py
            │   │   │   ├── newsfeed
            │   │   │   │   ├── app.yaml
            │   │   │   │   ├── facebookclient.py
            │   │   │   │   ├── static
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── base.css
            │   │   │   │   │   ├── favicon.ico
            │   │   │   │   │   └── robots.txt
            │   │   │   │   └── templates
            │   │   │   │       ├── base.html
            │   │   │   │       ├── home.html
            │   │   │   │       └── index.html
            │   │   │   ├── oauth
            │   │   │   │   ├── app.yaml
            │   │   │   │   ├── facebookoauth.py
            │   │   │   │   └── oauth.html
            │   │   │   └── tornado
            │   │   │       ├── example.html
            │   │   │       ├── example.py
            │   │   │       └── schema.sql
            │   │   ├── facebook.py
            │   │   ├── facebook_sdk.egg-info
            │   │   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
            │   │   │   ├── PKG-INFO
            │   │   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
            │   │   │   └── top_level.txt
            │   │   ├── MANIFEST.in
            │   │   ├── README.rst
            │   │   └── setup.py
            │   └── pip-delete-this-directory.txt
            ├── static
            │   └── js
            │       └── jquery-1.10.1.min.js
            ├── templates
            │   ├── 404.html
            │   ├── 500.html
            │   ├── Base.html
            │   ├── Home.html
            │   ├── Reoccurring.html
            │   └── Usersettings.html
            └── usersetting
                ├── admin.py
                ├── __init__.py
                ├── __init__.pyc
                ├── models.py
                ├── models.pyc
                └── views.py
```

my django.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www/quickerhub.com/')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/quickerhub.com.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

my httpd.conf:

my sites-enabled/quickerhub.com:

```
WSGIPythonPath /srv/www/quickerhub.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName quickerhub.com

    Alias /static/ /srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/static/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/django.wsgi

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

I feel like everything is pointing to the correct stuff...

EDIT:

Now just getting a 404 file not found

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: What is all that `VirtualHost` stuff doing in your WSGI file? Copy-and-paste error, or is that really there?

Comment: sorry, was error, corrected thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just setup my site [www.noobniche.com](http://www.noobniche.com) on Linode using WSGI.  Unfortunately I'm not at home to compare my setup, if you're still having problems tonight I can look into it.  From memory in my case, I had to enable by adding to sites-enabled and sites-available.

the structure should look something similar to this;

```
webapps(root directory)
    nichesite
        static
        django_project_name
            --> myproject.wsgi
            --> settings.py
            --> urls.py
            --> views.py
        manage.py
```

it seems your .wsgi file is located in your root directory, when it should be located within your django project folder.

Comment: ah I will try that and update here, would be very interested in your help later if your available!

Comment: ok I took your advice and moved django.wsgi into my project directory and now my `WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/django.wsgi` matches up with the actual location, but I am still receiving the 404 error at quickerhub.com. I've updated my directory listing above as well. my error log contains this after one attempt: `Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /srv/www` I feel like this is strange as the WSGI alias is not pointing to www...I also feel like it may be something to do with permissions possibly? I made loganhenson an admin but don't know if that is sufficient

Comment: also updated my enables site quickerhub.com, didn't help either :/

Comment: fixed the 404 by moving my entire directory, and now have a whole new slew of errors, new question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/520731/errors-serving-django-on-apache2-with-mod-wsgi

Comment: well you're on the right path now, you wsgi file is being found and now it's just your settings file not being found. your wsgi points to your projects settings.py file. Most likely your wsgi file needs to say myproject(whatever the name is)/settings.py specifically your error is in the last part of that log --> aise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)) [Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings

Answer (score 0):

So it looks as if you have conflicting settings for `WSGIScriptAlias` - one in httpd.conf, pointing to the right path for your wsgi file, and one in your sites-enabled file, pointing to the *wrong* path (`/var/` instead of `/srv/`).

You should remove the one in httpd.conf and move it to sites-enabled/quickerhub.com so that the version there is correctly pointing to `/srv/`.

Comment: I changed this and am still getting 404

Comment: [Wed Jul 03 12:51:10 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/2.8 Python/2.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 03 12:51:18 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /srv/www
[Wed Jul 03 12:51:18 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /srv/www
[Wed Jul 03 12:52:18 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /srv/www
[Wed Jul 03 12:52:18 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /srv/www

Comment: So, it's looking in the right place. Next thing to check is if the Apache user has the correct access rights for that directory and its children.

Comment: I changed 'WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/quickerhub.com/interest/django.wsgi' to 'WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/quickerhub.com/django.wsgi' and am recieving the same error, was it correct before?

Comment: well you're on the right path now, you wsgi file is being found and now it's just your settings file not being found. your wsgi points to your projects settings.py file. Most likely your wsgi file needs to say myproject(whatever the name is)/settings.py specifically your error is in the last part of that log --> aise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)) [Wed Jul 03 22:44:45 2013] [error] [client 74.192.126.252] ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings